# How to retrieve a target's relative runtime destination directory?

Tags: cmake, target, installation-path

Let's suppose I create a target as follows:

```
add_executable(app main.c)
install(TARGETS app
    RUNTIME DESTINATION some/path}
)
```

How do I retrieve `some/path` with a generator expression?

- `$<TARGET_FILE:tgt>` returns the full absolute path with the installation prefix
- `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:tgt>` does the same thing and includes the filename
- `$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:tgt>` only returns the filename, not the path

What am I missing? Is there a property that contains this information?

Answer (score 0):

There are neither generator expressions nor properties reflected **installation** path of particular target. All generator expressions you list reflect information about *build* location of the target.

There is `$<INSTALL_PREFIX>` generator expression, but it is available only when target is exported (`install(EXPORT)`) and only within this command invocation.

So, if you need destination directory of some target, you should manually write it. Or store it in some target's property and use `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:tgt,prop>` generator expression. [Note, that if your property reflects *relative* path, such generator expression cannot be used with `install` command, because this commands accepts only generator expressions which contain *absolute* path.]